# Does Visual Studio clean up memory automatically when it stop debugging a program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I am using Visual studio 2015, but I prefer a generic answer for every version.

If my code **has memory leak** and it run with **exit value = 0** inside Visual Studio (`F5`):-

- (Q1) In **debug** mode, will it really leak?
- (Q2) In **release** mode, will it really leak?

If my code **reserve some heap memory**, then I **terminate** it by pressing the red rectangle button (`stop`) before my code can release memory appropriately :-

- (Q3) In **debug** mode, will it really leak?
- (Q4) In **release** mode, will it really leak?

I notices my program slow down gradually after several `run->red button`, and become faster again after I restart my computer.   It might be just my imagination - or GPU-related.

However, I also remember a case of `run->allocate 10MB->red button` several times without any impact on performance of later runs.

Comment: When the program is closed, the OS will reclaim any memory allocated by it.

Comment: @DeiDei   I may misunderstand something seriously.  Do you really mean it?  If I allocate `char* x=new char[10000]` without release -> then run in release mode.  After my `.exe` exists, the 10000 bytes will be released back to OS?  If so, every memory leak from my program will not effect OS in long-run?  Therefore, restarting computer is unrelated to memory leak at all?

Comment: Debug or release mode does not matter. It will be freed when the program terminates.

Comment: @cppBeginner that is correct. The OS knows what memory your process has allocated and will reclaim that memory (if still allocated) when the process exits. Memory leaks affect the OS only while your process is actively running.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  Thank a lot.  I have misunderstood about it for than 5 years. ... blaming that my computer become slow down because program XXX that I just close has some memory leak.

Comment: @cppBeginner: Modern Operating Systems (Mac,Windows,Linux) for Personal Computers all clean up. There are specialized Operating Systems for embedded systems which don't, but they're generally invisible. E.g. a microwave may have a tiny OS. Smartphones nowadays are basically small PC's and also clean up.

Comment: @MSalters  Is the fact applicable to GPU (opengl)?  If my program reserve vertex buffer, then crash, will it leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

When the program exits, *no matter how it exits*, the operating system will free the program's memory.

Comment: May you provide some reference please?  This answer is beyond my imagination.

Comment: @cppBeginner: restarting the computer resets all memory back to a clean slate. Restarting the computer is not a solution to memory leaking, but a bad leak may warrant it if you don't exit the leaking process before available memory runs out

Comment: @Remy Lebeau That can explain a lot of thing, thank a lot.